# How to change the border of mdframed?

Tags: mdframed

I want to change the border color of the mdframe box. By default it take black.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newtheorem{mdtheorem}{Theorem}
 \newenvironment{theorem}%
 {\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=lightgray]\begin{mdtheorem}}%
 {\end{mdtheorem}\end{mdframed}}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{theorem}
Sample
\end{theorem}
 \end{document}
```

1. My Default output is,
   [image]
2. My Expected output is,
   [image]

Any one suggest me the correct. I am new to LaTeX.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The correct way to define a new theorem environment with `mdframed` is through the `\newmdtheoremenv` command.

The option to change the color of the frame border is `linecolor`. If you also want to change the width of the border, use the option `linewidth`.

If you then want to show only the bottom of the border, set to `false` the options `topline`, `rightline`, and `leftline`.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newmdtheoremenv[%
  backgroundcolor=lightgray,
  linecolor=red!60!black,
  linewidth=2pt,
  topline=false,
  rightline=false,
  leftline=false]{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
Sample
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I want to set the bottom line in that environment...@karlkoeller.

Comment: @PSK Oh, I see. Answer edited.