# How to add rule in color box?

Tags: pdftex, tcolorbox

I am new to latex i want to add rule in top and bottom of the color box,

My sample code is,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{pink}{\parbox{\textwidth}{%
 \vskip10pt
 \leftskip10pt\rightskip10pt
 \lipsum[1]
\vskip10pt
}
}
\end{document}
```

1. My Expected output is,

[image]

Any one help me to achieve this task.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for solutions with `\colorbox`? Otherwise, you should be able to do so with `mdframed` as it has been explained in [a question of yours](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164004/13304).

Comment: I looking for the solutions except `mdframed`. In `\colorbox` is this possible?

Comment: How about `\hrulefill` before and after the text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `\hrulefill` before and after your text, which doesn't give exactly the output you sketched, but which is easy to implement.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{pink}{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{%
        \hrulefill
        {% We don't want \...skip to affect \hrulefill
            \vskip10pt
            \leftskip10pt\rightskip10pt
            \lipsum[1]
            \vskip10pt
        }
        \hrulefill
    }
}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: You need `\noindent\colorbox{pink}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep\relax}{%...` in order to prevent overfull boxes; you also need to comment out a spurious blank space after the nect to last closing brace.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newmdenv[
hidealllines=true,
backgroundcolor=pink,
topline=true,
bottomline=true,
linewidth=3pt,
linecolor=red
]{mybox}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
 \lipsum[1]
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thak you it is working.

Answer (score 3):

You could stack it.  Note that I played with your `\parbox` width to make the box fall within the proper margins.  I also took the liberty of placing it in a separate macro `\mycolorbox`.  Note that it cannot break across page boundaries.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\parskip 1ex
\newcommand\mycolorbox[1]{%
\par\noindent\stackunder[-3pt]{\stackon[-3pt]{%
\colorbox{pink}{\parbox{\textwidth-10pt}{%
 \vskip10pt
 \leftskip10pt\rightskip10pt
 #1
\vskip10pt
}
}%
}{\color{blue}\hsmash{\rule{\textwidth+10pt}{3pt}}}%
}{\color{blue}\hsmash{\rule{\textwidth+10pt}{3pt}}}
\par}
\begin{document}
\mycolorbox{\lipsum[1]}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I misunderstood about making the rules extend slightly into the margins, you can make them `\textwidth` without the `+10pt` addition (or smaller ).  Here is a variation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\parskip 1ex
\newcommand\mycolorbox[1]{%
\par\noindent\stackunder[-5pt]{\stackon[-5pt]{%
\colorbox{pink}{\parbox{\textwidth-10pt}{%
 \vskip10pt
 \leftskip10pt\rightskip10pt
 #1
\vskip10pt
}
}%
}{\color{blue!70}\hsmash{\rule{\textwidth-4pt}{2pt}}}%
}{\color{blue!70}\hsmash{\rule{\textwidth-4pt}{2pt}}}
\par}
\begin{document}
\mycolorbox{\lipsum[1]}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make it in any other color like green, blue? ..@Steven B. Segletes

Comment: Sorry you misunderstanding my question..I asked the color of the `rule`.@Steven B. Segletes

Comment: @PSK  Aha.  Done.

Answer (score 3):

With [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{Mybox}{
  colback=pink!90!black,
  colframe=black,
  arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt,
  boxrule=0pt,
  toprule=3pt,
  bottomrule=3pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{Mybox}
\lipsum[1]
\end{Mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Previous example is the classic one, but with `tcolorbox` we can do more *interesting* boxes.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{Mybox}{
  width={\linewidth-6pt},
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  colback=pink,
  colframe=black,
  arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt,
  boxrule=0pt,
  toprule=0pt,
  bottomrule=0pt,
  enlarge top by=5mm,
  overlay ={
    \draw[gray,thick] ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west)--([yshift=5mm]frame.north)--([xshift=-5mm]frame.north east);
    \draw[fill=gray] ([yshift=4.5mm]frame.north) circle(3pt);
    \draw[line width=3pt, blue!30!black, shorten >=-3pt, shorten < = -3pt] (frame.north west)--(frame.north east);
    \draw[line width=3pt, blue!30!black, shorten >=-3pt, shorten < = -3pt] (frame.south west)--(frame.south east);
  }
}

\newenvironment{Mypage}
{\par\centering\begin{Mybox}}{\end{Mybox}\par}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-3]
\begin{Mypage}
\lipsum[1]
\end{Mypage}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I was adding the `tcolorbox` option to my answer when you published yours. I'll delete the tcolorbox option from my answer.