# Boxed caption and figure, with colored caption

Tags: floats, color, boxes

I'm trying to recreate a figure and caption effect from a journal. An example of it can be seen on PDF version of Figure 1 from [this article](http://www.beilstein-journals.org/bjnano/single/articleFullText.htm?publicId=2190-4286-5-133):

[image]

It's basically a large grey bordered box that goes around the image and caption, and the bottom section, where the caption is filled in grey.

I'm currently using

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{mystyle1}{
    backgroundcolor=white!20
}
\mdfdefinestyle{mystyle2}{
    backgroundcolor=lightgray!20
}
```

in the preamble, and

```
\begin{figure}[htb!]
\centering
    \begin{mdframed}[style=mystyle1]
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{foo.pdf}
        \begin{mdframed}[style=mystyle2]
            \caption[foo]{foo}
        \end{mdframed}
    \end{mdframed}
\label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}
```

This creates a box around the whole figure and caption, and then a subbox around the caption, but they don't lineup, and I can't figure out how to change the border colour.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The question would be improved by including a complete compilable minimal example, so that those trying to help do have to put such a file together, see [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 4):

Below I present one option using [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) to define a `figurebox` environment. This environment has an optional argument to specify placement options (just as for the standard figure environment).

Instead of using two boxes, I just used one box; the upper part is used for the image and the lower one, for the caption. Use `\tcblower` just before `\caption`.

The [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package was used to easily change the color for the caption labels. Change the settings according to your needs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{captioncol}{RGB}{46,86,145}

\newtcolorbox{mycaptionbox}{
  freelance,
  enhanced,
  colframe=gray,
  arc=0pt,
  middle=2pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  boxrule=0.7pt,
  enlarge left by=-5mm,
  enlarge right by=-5mm,
  text width=\textwidth-1.4pt,
  nobeforeafter,
  segmentation hidden=true,
  interior code={
  \path[draw=none,fill=gray!30]
    (interior.south west) rectangle (segmentation.north east);
  \path[draw=none,fill=white]
    (segmentation.west) rectangle (interior.north east);
  \draw[draw=gray,line width=0.7pt]
    (segmentation.west) -- (segmentation.east);
  },
}

\newenvironment{figurebox}[1][tbp]
  {\begin{figure}[#1]\begin{mycaptionbox}}
  {\end{mycaptionbox}\end{figure}}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{colorlabel}{\textcolor{captioncol}{#1#2}#3}
\captionsetup{format=colorlabel}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{figurebox}
\includegraphics[height=3cm,width=.6\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\tcblower
\caption{\protect\lipsum[2]}
\end{figurebox}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by lining up? To change the border color please look at the answer from this link:
[How to change the border of mdframed?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164004/how-to-change-the-border-of-mdframed)
Here is the result on my computer

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{mystyle1}{
    backgroundcolor=white!20,
    linecolor=red
}
\mdfdefinestyle{mystyle2}{
    backgroundcolor=lightgray!20,
    linecolor=blue
}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb!]
\begin{mdframed}[style=mystyle1]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[domain=-1:1] {x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{mdframed}[style=mystyle2]
    \caption{Caption.}
  \end{mdframed}
\end{mdframed}
\label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Here is what the result on my computer using pdflatex]